# Spark Scala Encoder Case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to convert a DataFrame into a Dataset of case class. In my example in Dataset[Product]. I did a lot of research in web site but I didn't find the good solution.

My SparkSession:

```
lazy val sparkSession: SparkSession =
SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

My case class:

```
case class Product(product_category: Int,
                   product_name: String
                   )
```

Treatment:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
df.select($"product_category",$"product_name").as[Product]
```

In my case use **sparkSession.implicits._** doesn't have an impact to resolve this error:

```
 Error: (33, 31) Unable to find encoder for type Product. An implicit Encoder[Ex2Amount] is needed to store Product instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

How can I handle manage this error correctly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure you define the case class outside the main method.

Comment: I don't have a main method in the class

Comment: you are running this from spark-shell? If not then you probably run it under a main class in a scala program. If so try to place the Product class outside the container class

Comment: The error shows an `Ex2Amount` that you did not show. Also, please edit your question to provide **Spark** & **Scala** _versions_.